# User login to database from application

Tags: java, for-loop

This one has been bugging me for a little bit and I can't for the life of me figure it out:

I have to get my application to collect input from the user as a means of logging in to a database. My issue is, only the first user is actually allowed in according to the code. What am I doing wrong?

**CODE**

```
for(int i=0;i<numRows;i++)
        {
            String Usernames = rs.getString("Username");
            String Password = rs.getString("Password");
            String getAcc = rs.getString("UserType");
            rs.next();
            if(Usernames.trim().equals(UsernameIn)&&Password.trim().equals(PasswordIn))
            {
                start.writeToFile("ConToDatabase Class|Username: "+UsernameIn+" and Password: "+PasswordIn+" Accepted");
                if(getAcc.trim().equals("admin"))
                {
                    start.writeToFile("ConToDatabase Class|Authenticated user identified as \"admin\", Entering AdminUser Class|UTypeAdmin Method");
                    clear();
                    AdminUser.UTypeAdmin(args, UsernameIn, rs, dbTable(), path);
                }
                if(getAcc.trim().equals("standard"))
                {
                    start.writeToFile("ConToDatabase Class|Authenticated user identified as \"standard\", Entering StandardUser Class|UTypeStandard Method");
                    clear();
                    StandardUser.UTypeStandard(args, UsernameIn, rs, dbTable(),path);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                start.writeToFile("ConToDatabase Class|User invalid, reset application");
                System.out.println("Invalid User, Resetting...");
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                ConToDatabase.clearandreset(args);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why are you obtaining all the users from database and validate them against your single user? It would be better to check if there's this single user registered in database.

Comment: So something like:

String Username = rs.getString("Username")
String Password = rs.getString("Password)
---
if(Username.contains(UsernameIn||Password.cotains(PasswordIn)
//doStufff

Comment: No, something like `SELECT <columns> FROM <user table> WHERE username = ? AND password = ?` and set `username` and `password` as parameters to the query by using `PreparedStatement`. This is way better than retrieving all users from database and use a `for` loop to check if your user exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is the code in your ELSE block.

You want to test all the users before say that the user is invalid.

With the first user you dont have that problem because you only arrived to the IF block code, but with all the other users you gonna pass by the ELSE block at least once.

You can do something like this:

```
boolean founded = false;
for(int i=0;i<numRows;i++)
{
    String Usernames = rs.getString("Username");
    String Password = rs.getString("Password");
    String getAcc = rs.getString("UserType");
    rs.next();

    if(Usernames.trim().equals(UsernameIn)&&Password.trim().equals(PasswordIn))
    {
        founded = true;
        start.writeToFile("ConToDatabase Class|Username: "+UsernameIn+" and Password: "+PasswordIn+" Accepted");

        if(getAcc.trim().equals("admin"))
        {
            start.writeToFile("ConToDatabase Class|Authenticated user identified as \"admin\", Entering AdminUser Class|UTypeAdmin Method");
            clear();
            AdminUser.UTypeAdmin(args, UsernameIn, rs, dbTable(), path);
        }

        if(getAcc.trim().equals("standard"))
        {
            start.writeToFile("ConToDatabase Class|Authenticated user identified as \"standard\", Entering StandardUser Class|UTypeStandard Method");
            clear();
            StandardUser.UTypeStandard(args, UsernameIn, rs, dbTable(),path);
        }
    }
}

if(!founded)
{ 
  start.writeToFile("ConToDatabase Class|User invalid, reset application");
  System.out.println("Invalid User, Resetting...");
  Thread.sleep(2000);
  ConToDatabase.clearandreset(args);
}
```

You want to pay attention at the comments in your answer too.